# Print Multipage in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing

i have to print my form but it is big to enter in only one page so i need to print it in 2 pages ,my poor knowledge allow me to know how print one page but hot how print in multipage .
Do you have any advice how i can print in multipage,all kind of help will be appreciate.

Thanks.

Good Work

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the [DocumentPaginator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.documentpaginator.aspx) class.

This [blog post](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination) helped me get it working.

What I did was create a `UserControl` that would show one page's (any of the pages) worth of data.

Then in the override for `GetPage` I created the `UserControl` (passing it the page number to render), then measured and arranged it (using the `PageSize` from the `DocumentPaginator`), and returned it as a `DocumentPage` (by passing it to the constructor of `DocumentPage`).

Then you need to override `PageCount` and `PageSize`, so that when `PageSize` is updated, the `PageCount` is changed.

Comment: Hi Ray,your link is helpful,Thanks so much... with it i can print in multipage ,but i did not understand in my case ,i have a document where i store data with databinding (Report) and i dont know how use the example of the blog in my case.I Created my UserControl but without luck.
Do you have any help for that.
However thanks again

Comment: Sorry, the only printing I've done matched the blog post pretty closely and don't have any experience outside of that. The only suggestion I would have is to try and make your UserControl be able to display just a single page of data and be able to choose whether it shows the first or second page.