# How to print long bill in WPF

Tags: wpf, printing

I have a WPF application for product purchase billing. My client wants that app should be able to bill and print upto 1-99 products at once. they use bill printer (mini size printer) for billing. How I can achieve this in WPF C#. Any code or link would be helpful.

Thank you...

Comment: Here is a link that will probably help: http://tinyurl.com/363utsl :-)

Comment: Brad, point to a duplicate on SO. Otherwise it's a valid question.

Comment: Henk, you're right - however I did provide an actual answer (which I've just updated with some extra SO links). The comment was more for humor value.

Comment: I saw that, but still. Be nice to newbies etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you will want to print more than a page worth of data - in which case you should look at paginating the results.

The following is a great tutorial on how to do just that:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-printing-part-2-pagination

Some additional links from SO:

- [Print Multipage in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866678/print-multipage-in-wpf)
- [WPF - pagination when printing a visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2211302/wpf-pagination-when-printing-a-visual)
- [How Print multipage WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023401/how-print-multipage-wpf)
- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wpf+printing